# Detectar o fechamento do navegador ou guia

Tags: javascript, jquery

Existe algum código JavaScript/jQuery entre navegadores para detectar se o navegador ou uma guia do navegador está sendo fechada?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize o evento `.unload()`.
https://api.jquery.com/unload/

**Jquery < 3.0**

```
$(window).unload(function() {
  alert("call");
  console.log("this will be triggered");
});
```

**Jquery >= 1.7**

```
$(window).on("unload", function(e) {
  alert("call");
  console.log("this will be triggered");
});
```

> *The unload event is sent to the window element when the user navigates away from the page. This could mean one of many things. The user could have clicked on a link to leave the page, or typed in a new URL in the address bar. The forward and back buttons will trigger the event. Closing the browser window will cause the event to be triggered. Even a page reload will first create an unload event.*
>
> **O evento unload é enviado para o elemento window quando o usuário navega para fora da página. Isso pode significar uma de muitas coisas. O usuário poderia ter clicado em um link para sair da página ou digitar um novo URL na barra de endereço. Os botões para frente e para trás acionarão o evento. Fechar a janela do navegador fará com que o evento seja acionado. Até mesmo um recarregamento de página primeiro criará um evento de descarregamento.**

*google tradutor*

Comment: Isso funciona em todos navegadores?

"Blocked alert('call') during unload."

Comment: A compatibilidade do Jquery vc pode ver aqui: https://jquery.com/browser-support/

Comment: Obrigada. Vou dar uma pesquisada, estou usando a última versão do jQuery (3.3.1).

Comment: @Tfm veja a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/unload) do evento unload. Este evento ocorre antes da página ser descarregada da memória, então a interface já não está mais operacional, ou seja, funções como `window.open`, `alert` e `confirm` não funcionarão.

Comment: Talvez você queira utilizar o evento [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload).